# Кэш для нагруженного веб приложения

Tags: java, spring, кэширование, concurrency

Приложение отдает одинаковые данные клиентам. Например список стран. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы не нужно было постоянно дергать базу, а при первом запуске приложения считывать в кэш этот справочник и отдавать по запросу. Дело в том, что кэш должен жить постоянно, естественно пока работает приложение. Раз в сутки приложение будет проверять если изменения в БД по справочнику и если, да то дописывать эти изменения в кэш. Для этих целей я выбрал `ConcurrentHashMap<>` Как считаете подойдет ли такая структура для этих целей и нормальная ли эта идея держать это в кэше. Можно ли сделать кэш с пагинацией, что-то вроде `Page` или придется считывать все, а потом дробить на страницы и хранить уже в кэше? Приоритетом в таком выборе была скорость ответа.

Comment: 1. почему `Map`? что в роли ключа будет? 2. сюда подойдет и `List`. 3. Пагинация применяется в основном при выборе из бд. А тут смысл от нее, если все данные и так уже есть.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap<Id, List<Countries> ` где Id - айдишник языка клиента. Это просто пример. Можно и `List` Допустим в кэше 100к строк. И нужно отдавать порциями по 100 строк на запрос. А каком-то роде пагинация. Чтобы клиент не получался все сразу.

Comment: а `id` языка берется из бд? Возможно проще будет в роли ключа использовать код языка: `RU`, `EN` и т.д. Меньше запросов в бд.

Comment: Представим, что у клиента определился `id` с нужным языком. Например это Android и он получил до этого `List<Languages>` и с нужным айдишником  к нам стучится.

Comment: а у Вас REST сервис?

Comment: Да, обычный REST на Spring

Comment: Значит при каждом обращении на сервер у Вас будет проверятся и вытаскиваться пользователь из бд. Как Вы будете складывать `LanguageId` -> `List<Country>`? сначала получите все языки, а потом к языку страны?

Comment: Может тогда 2 мапы друг в друге (язык и пейдж), а в последней мапе лист?

Comment: Хочу написать свое решение с пагинацией. Сделал `Map<Long, Map<Long, List<Object>>>` . Структура кэша такая `<id категории, <страница, List<сущность>>>`. Каждый день в одно и тоже время система обновляет кэш и раскладывает сущности по категориям, и делает пагинацию для категорий по собственному алгоритму. При каждой загрузке клиента он запрашивает список катеогрий и тоже получает из кэша. Все это, по идее, должно ускорить ответ от сервера. Но в кэше будет вся база. Думаю памятью можно пожертвовать ради скорости.